# 'The org cannot be found' error in VS Code

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx-cli, visualstudiocode, cli

Anyone experienced "The org cannot be found" issue in VS Code. I'm facing this issue from past 2 weeks. Tried with multiple orgs. Un-installed and re-installed VS Code. Tried with different versions of VS Code. Updated CLI to the latest version. Tried with last 2-3 versions of SF CLI. I'm not behind any VPN.

No issue with any of the org's setting because I see that the same org working well in other systems. This behaviour is the same for different orgs. (Not org specific)

I can able to authorize the org and open default org works a couple of times without any error. But most of the times it returns the same error. Retrieve and deploy works the very first time after launching VS code and then returns the same error when I try again and few other times, it doesn't work for the first time as well.

Comment: Please, refrain from asking generic "help me" questions. Try to provide details in order to reproduce your issue. e.g. are you using cli commands or vscode extensions? Which is the version of vscode,? Which is the version of extensions/cli?

Comment: I tried the same versions in another machine and its working completely fine. So I couldn't replicate the same. I'm using salesforce extension pack(v56.16.0) from VS code extensions. VS Code version: 1.75.1 CLI Version: sfdx-cli/7.187.1

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue with my VS code. The version which I was using for sfdx cli was 7.187.1. So I updated the sfdx cli and try to deploy my component and it get deployed.